# Show there is no intersection between sequence of balls on an open set.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a way to show that a finite sequence of balls, in an open set $U ⊆ C$, with a small enough radius's such that there is no intersection between any of the balls? Intuitively it makes sense to me and I wondered if there was a rigorous way to show it.

For balls centred on
$$z_1, z_2, . . . , z_n ∈ U \text{ for some finite n} ∈ \mathbb{N}$$
Show that
$$B_r(z_k)  ∩ B_r(z_j) = ∅ \text{ if } k\neq j  \text{ }\forall 1\leq k,j\leq n  $$
I have no idea how you begin to go about this, probably showing that you can have 2 balls that have no intersection. For $z,w \in C$

$B_r(z)  ∩ B_r(w) = ∅ $ iff $r\leq\frac{|z-w|}{2}$

I would imagine this has been shown somewhere but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: $$r = \frac 1 {42} \min_{j \ne k} |z_k - z_j|$$

Comment: @T.Bongers Where are you getting $\frac{1}{42}$ from? Wouldn't $\frac{1}{2}$ suffice?

Comment: Because I like 42 better.